# jQuery replace method is not updating old value with new value

Tags: jquery, replace

I am trying to Replace Old Values with New Values in P Tag By Using JQuery replace(String SearchValue, String replaceValue) Method on buton click. if I pass Fixed Values then it update but when I Pass through input text Box then it doesn't.

I used Different method to Solve this problem even tried on internet but no salutation .

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="" id="TxtOne" name="TxtOne" placeholder="Old Word" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" value="" id="TxtTwo" name="TxtTwo" placeholder="New Word" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="button" onclick="ChangeData();" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" id="btnOne" name="btnOne" style="float:right" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to replace hate with Love

```
<script>
    function ChangeData() {
        var oldData = $('#TxtOne').val();
        oldData = '/' + oldData + '/ig';
        var newData = $('#TxtTwo').val();
        var $p = $('p');
        $p.text($p.text().replace(oldData, newData));
        //$p.text($p.text().replace(/hate/ig, 'love'));
    };
</script>
```

No Result

Comment: is this function being called anywhere?

Comment: on button click

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (including input and expected output) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is not a jQuery function, it's a JavaScript function.

Comment: `oldData = '/' + oldData + '/ig'` doesn't magically generate a regular expression object.

Comment: What is the alternative  to generate regular expression could you suggest any salutation, Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you cannot build a regular expression by doing:

```
oldData = '/' + oldData + '/ig';
```

Instead, you can use the `RegExp` constructor to build your expression and use that in your `replace` method.

Also, here I am passing an arrow function into the `.text()` method which will set the text equal to whatever it returns.

See example below:

```js
$("#btnOne").click(ChangeData);

function ChangeData() {
  var oldData = new RegExp($('#TxtOne').val(), 'ig');
  var newData = $('#TxtTwo').val();
  $('p').text((_, txt) => txt.replace(oldData, newData));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>I want to replace hate with love</p>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" value="" id="TxtOne" name="TxtOne" placeholder="Old Word" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" value="" id="TxtTwo" name="TxtTwo" placeholder="New Word" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" id="btnOne" name="btnOne" style="float:right" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note, however, the `RegExp` creates a regular expression, and so it may behave unexpectedly if special characters are used in the input.

Comment: this will only work if `oldData` doesn't contain any characters that would have a special meaning when used in a regular expression.

Comment: Yes Now it works fine, Thanks for solving my Code Problem Mr. Nick Parsons,

Comment: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)